# Copying entire directory using MSBuild

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild

I have the following on an ASP.NET Core 3.1 application:

```
<Target Name="OnBuild" BeforeTargets="Build">
  <Exec WorkingDirectory="approot" Command="npm run build --prod" />
  <Copy SourceFiles="approot\dist" DestinationFolder="wwwroot" />
</Target>
```

When I build I get an error:

```
The source file "approot/dist" is actually a directory.  
The "Copy" task does not support copying directories.
```

How can I copy the directory `approot\dist` to `wwwroot` using MSBuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Target Name="OnBuild" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Folder Include="**\approot\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(Folder)" DestinationFolder="wwwroot\%(RecursiveDir)"></Copy>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue using the xCopy syntax below:

```
<Exec Command="xcopy "approot\dist" "wwwroot" /S /Y /I" />
```

Where:

- approot\dist - source path
- wwwroot - destination path
- /Y - Suppresses the confirmation to overwrite the destination file if it exists.
- /I - If the destination does not exist, this option assumes that the goal is a directory and creates it. If you omit this option, the command prompts you to confirm if the destination is a directory or a file.
- /S - Copies folders and subfolders recursively, excluding the empty ones.